# What's the name of the "Now Playing" bar in the bottom of Play Music?

Tags: java, android, xml

This is the screenshot from Google Play Music, and what's the name of the widget in the bottom of the layout?(circled with red)

When user swipe it up or click it, the cover page will show up, which can be closed by swiping down on the screen -- and that's what I need((XDDD

Thx.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's any standard by Android Developer, but I found this. It seems pretty similar.

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

> This library provides a simple way to add a draggable sliding up panel (popularized by Google Music and Google Maps) to your Android application. Brought to you by Umano. http://umano.me

Comment: And here is a simple tutorial. 
http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/05/making-sliding-up-panel-like-google.html

Comment: That's a choice indeed! Thanks thobber! By the way I also wonder if there is any official standard of it. Would it be a vertical SlidingDrawer?